# Is there any public webservice available for the list of Places in a country?

Tags: web-services

I am working on a travel site where i need all the places list in a country. So instead of storing and updating it in the database I wanted to use a webservice to use.Please let me know if any similar webservice is available

Comment: 'All the places list in a country'? To what level of detail? Postcode areas? Towns & cities? Individual street addresses? Please scope your question.

Comment: Maybe here > www.webservicex.net/WS/wscatlist.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this google places api, i think its the most comprehensive since it is based on google maps

[google Places Api](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the data from open street map:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/

Comment: +1, that's what I was just about to suggest http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data